# Duplicate Image in Gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image gallery that displays all the images inline, and the targeted image displayed bigger elsewhere on the page. The problem I'd like to solve is to make the targeted image bigger, without removing it from the gallery flow.

```
<div class="gallery">
    <a href="#1"><img id="1" src="http://placehold.it/100" /></a>
    <a href="#2"><img id="2" src="http://placehold.it/200" /></a>
    <a href="#3"><img id="3" src="http://placehold.it/300" /></a>
    <a href="#4"><img id="4" src="http://placehold.it/400" /></a>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GxxV5/

i.e, when say image 200 is displayed larger, I'd like it to also remain in the top gallery view, rather than just moving to the bottom of the page.

Ideally there's an html/css solution?
I'd be okay with a javascript solution, but please no jquery. I'm still learning javascript before I move on to jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Stijntjhe/xxBEd/

Not much JavaScript at all, put it in your `<head>`:

```
function show(img) {
    document.getElementById('big').innerHTML = '<img src="' + img.src + '" />';   
}
```

And add a simple `onclick` to your images:

```
<img id="2" onclick="show(this);" src="http://placehold.it/200" />
```

Don't forget the extra `<div>` in your HTML:

```
<div id="big"></div>
```

**EDIT:**

It's even possible without JavaScript, but you would need some extra HTML:
http://jsfiddle.net/Stijntjhe/xxBEd/5/

Comment: This almost works, the main problems being 1. Both the new item and the old are changing size and 2. The new item isn't on the bottom of the page (this doesn't /need/ to be fixed, ideally the images will be large enough to fill the space)

Comment: I just changed the CSS to solve those problems:
http://jsfiddle.net/Stijntjhe/xxBEd/4/

Comment: Looks good! I'm trying to figure out how to essentially move the css from img:target to the next #big selector. So far I've only copy-pasted from img:target to #big > img but it's not doing what I want...

Comment: I was thinking about that, but my galleries have anywhere from 20 to 50 images, and that would double load time. I suppose I could use thumbnails though.

Comment: Then just use my JavaScript solution.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it wasn't working how I wanted, but it seems that it is. Thank you for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I just add a basic javascript function into your sample like:

```
function showMe(img, size) {
    document.getElementById("content").src = img.src;
    document.getElementById("content").style.width = size + "px";
    document.getElementById("content").style.height = size + "px";
}
```

You can see the full change at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GxxV5/2/). Please help me add some css to beaufity it, ;)