# Replace attribute with an index value in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of images (thumbs) near a container with one image. I want jQuery to count the index of the `<a>` element, and then replace the number of the src attribute of the image below.

I mean, considering this code:

```
<ul class="thumbs">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img1.jpg" alt="image here"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img2.jpg" alt="image here"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img3.jpg" alt="image here"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="img4.jpg" alt="image here"/></a></li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
    <img src="img1.jpg" alt="destiny image here"/>
</div>
```

The expected behavior is, when user clicks the second `<a>`, the `.container img` change its src attribute to `img1.jpg`. And when click the fourth `<a>` the attribute should change to `img3.jpg`.

I have got this far: [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HvTpv/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".thumbs li a").click(function () {
        //$('div.container').toggleClass('on');
        var index = $(".thumbs li a").index(this);
        $("div.container img[src^='img']").replaceWith("img" + index + ".jpg");
    });
});
```

It doesn't does absolutely nothing. I don't think to understand properly the .replaceWith method.

Also, the commented line works fine when it's alone... when the rest of code is present `div.container` don't change its class. Is this related to the way I declare the variable?

Comment: Is this your actual code? `"div.container img[src^="img"]"` is a syntax error. Watch your quotes. Also, `replaceWith()` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799984/duplicate-image-in-gallery/17800221#17800221

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't replacing the attribute, you are replacing the img element.

you need to set the attribute with `.attr('src', value)`.

`replaceWith()` is for replacing elements with other html elements.

Comment: That's, that's it what I was searching for! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple, get rid of the index. Just get the `src`. Use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".thumbs li a").click(function () {
        //Get the src of the clicked image
        var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

        //Set the src to the container image
        $("div.container img").attr('src', src);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Stijntjhe/HvTpv/5/

Comment: It's hard to see it working without working images. Use Chrome's console to inspect the element.

Comment: the code would also benefit from event delegation - use `$('.thumbs').on('click', 'li a', ...)`

Comment: this is the answer. more concise

Comment: not least because using `.index()` will require an off-by-one adjustment because it's zero-based.

Comment: I like your solution too, is even more elegant. I'll give the accepted answer to Brad because it match more with the question (for other users who wants to do something with the .index method), but thank you very much indeed ;)

Comment: @Arkana I would note that the accepted answer fails to point out that `.index()` will start at _zero_, and not at 1, thus showing the wrong image.

Comment: Brad's also doesn't solve the selector problem `$("div.container img[src^='img']")`, mine does.

Comment: I tried Brad's code and works fine, it isn't...? Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HvTpv/7/). Also, it's true that `.index()` starts at zero, but I doesn't really mind, because I can set whatever name for the images. @Stijn, I really like your solution too, hope I could give you +10, but I think the more accurate answer is from Brad. If within a few views, your answer collects more votes it will mean that it helps more people, and then I'll be glad to change the accepted.